# What power(s) did Hiro's father have?

Tags: powers, heroes

I've been re-watching season one of Heroes. It seems like almost everyone initially introduced is the offspring of two people with powers. Hiro's mom was a healer, what powers did his dad have?

Comment: You mean you're rewatching the only good season of Heroes.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaito_Nakamura#Kaito_Nakamura)

> He has the power of **studying a situation and predicting its outcomes**, though in the series he never uses this ability.

And in the [notes section of heroeswiki](http://heroeswiki.com/Kaito_Nakamura#Notes)

> In a deleted scene from Four Months
>   Later, **Kaito reveals his "special ability" to Ando. Kaito says he can "see the variables of any situation and predict the outcome."** He claims he
>   is faster than a computer and
>   attributes his success in the stock
>   market to this ability. This ability
>   is similar to accelerated probability.
>   In Season Three, this same description
>   is used by Peter to describe Sylar's
>   intuitive aptitude. **However, it should also be noted that the deleted scene is not canonical, and Kaito has not been confirmed to have an ability.** Of
>   note, Bob said in the episode Four
>   Months Later..., "The Company was
>   formed thirty years ago with a group
>   of like-minded individuals, ordinary
>   men and women who were gifted with
>   extraordinary powers." Kaito was one of these founders. **Kaito's Primatech file also listed an ability for him,**
>   thought the file was damaged to the
>   point of illegibility.

Answer (score 0):

Hiro's father didn't have any special powers, he was merely a normal person. He was introduced as everyone from The Company, as has been seen in later seasons. See the [Hero's Wiki](http://heroeswiki.com/Kaito_Nakamura) entry on his father.

Comment: If he helped found the Company, he wasn't a normal person.  The founders ALL had abilities.